# When using Selenium Webdriver, I get the following error using the InternetExplorerDriver - "Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer...."

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to instantiate an InternetExplorerDriver in C#, and every time I do I get the following error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (NoSuchDriver)

Now I'm not sure how to sort this out, but the line of code that triggers the error in question is:

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

The documentation for InternetExplorerDriver suggests that I can pass in an `ICapabilities` object in an overloaded constructor, but that only has the properties `BrowserName`, `IsJavaScriptEnabled`, `Platform` and `Version`. None of these seem to suggest that they can solve the issue.

Is there something I need to do within the implementation to sort this out?
Or do I have to modify some settings within IE9 itself?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Internet Explorer defines four zones, each with a different security level and the ability to enable or disable Protected Mode. The error message is trying to tell you that Protected Mode must either be disabled or enabled for **all** zones because of a limitation in Selenium's `InternetExplorerDriver`.

For more details, see the [defect report in Selenium's issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1795) and the [screenshot of Internet Explorer security options](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1795#c19).

Comment: The second link (to the screenshot) is broken.

Comment: Nope still broken for me.. I'm not logged in to google (if I need to be logged in to see it, it's not actually on the web)

Answer (score 27):

For reference, if your wish to override the security options here's the c# code:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Test
    {
       private IWebDriver driver;

       [SetUp]
       public void Setup()
       {
          var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
          options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
          driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
       }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
My previous answer used an older version of Selenium 2.0, I've now updated the code to work against Selenium DotNet-2.21.0 and included the correct namespaces.

Comment: This code is obsolete - it gives 2 compile warnings, and fails to run.

Comment: what version of Selenium are you using? what error did you get?

Comment: It doesn't have a declaration for driver as that's been defined in the OP's original code. I will look up my codebase where I got this from and retest.

Answer (score 8):

This should solve the problem:

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 5):

Aleh's Answer resolved the issue for me, but I found I also needed to specify the file path for the location of the `IEDriverServer`. Just posting in case anyone else runs into a similar issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace SeleniumTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
            options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;

            IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver("C:\\Selenium", options);

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the following worked for me (none of the answers above worked)

```
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
desiredCapabilities.SetCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings, true);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(desiredCapabilities);
```

I found that it worked, but I also recieved an "(Unexpected Alert Open)" when I tried to run a test, which of all things, turned out I had to disable the IE developer toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

Refer link: -
https://intensetesting.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/error-80070012-unexpected-error-launching-spoon-based-internet-explorer/

If you upgrade or degrade the native IE browser which was installed during OS installation it will not allow opening the spoon browsers. Every time we need to make the default IE browser then it will work.
Suppose while you installed the OS the default IE version is IE8 and you upgraded to IE9 for some purpose. In this case it won’t allow navigating any application in the Spoon browsers (only browser will open up) and it will simply throw the error message like “Unexpected error launching internet explorer IELaunchURL error returned 80070012”.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem on a server that was built and I had no way of changing the protected mode. It was disabled by the system administrator. Even when I logged in with an admin account, I was unable to change the protected mode. However, I was able to run selenium with no problem.